# Google Assistant Custom Intent not working

Tags: android, flutter, google-assistant, app-actions

Google Assistant Custom Intent not working in Google Play Console Internal Test Build it's working find in App Action Test tool.

Can you please help me what issue in my code.

**Shortcut.xml**

```xml
<capability
    android:name="custom.actions.intent.OperationsSupport"
    app:queryPatterns="@array/operationalSupportArray">
    <app-widget
        android:identifier="OperationsSupport"
      android:targetClass="com.example.app.widgets.support.OperationSupportWidgetProvider"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.app">
        <extra
            android:name="hasTts"
            android:value="true" />
    </app-widget>
</capability>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<receiver
    android:name=".widgets.support.OperationSupportWidgetProvider"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/operations_support_widget" />
</receiver>
```

```xml
<service
    android:name=".widgets.support.OperationSupportWidgetProvider"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="com.google.assistant.appactions.widgets.PIN_APP_WIDGET" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```